# Python: Need to locate the value in the df column and select all records after it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got this pretty simple question, I guess.

So, I got a DF column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWWs7.png)

Essentially what I am trying to do is to locate the value "11006939" in the column and select all below/remaining values including search value.

The function should return df with the following column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSVsk.png)

Thanks for the help

```
def missing_reg_nums():
    df = pd.read_csv("df_1.csv")
    loc = df["num"].get_loc(11006939)
    print(loc)
```

Comment: Solved the problem myself. Please ignore above question.

Comment: then you should either delete the question, or post the answer and accept it...